# Tail bound of sum less than sum of tail bounds

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

> Problem: Suppose we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, P)$, a random variable $X$ on this space, and two nonnegative measurable functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to[0, \infty)$. Choose some $\epsilon > 0$. Prove that 
>   $$P(f(X)+g(X)>\epsilon) \le P(f(X)>\epsilon/2) + P(g(X)>\epsilon/2)$$

Attempt: by definition we know $P(f(X)+g(X)>\epsilon) = P(\{\nu \vert f(X)(\nu)+g(X)(\nu)))>\epsilon\})$, and it seems like a basic real analysis exercise, however I'm having trouble splitting this term into the two desired terms. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that
$$ \{ \nu \in \Omega \mid f(X)(\nu) + g(X)(\nu) > \epsilon \} \subset \{ \nu \in \Omega \mid f(X) (\nu) > \tfrac \epsilon 2\} \ \cup \ \{ \nu \in \Omega \mid g(X) (\nu) > \tfrac \epsilon 2\}. $$

So
\begin{align*} P\left( \{ \nu \in \Omega \mid f(X)(\nu) + g(X)(\nu) > \epsilon \}\right) & \leq P \left( \{ \nu \in \Omega \mid f(X) (\nu) > \tfrac \epsilon 2\} \ \cup \ \{ \nu \in \Omega \mid g(X) (\nu) > \tfrac \epsilon 2\} \right) \\ & \leq P \left( \{ \nu \in \Omega \mid f(X) (\nu) > \tfrac \epsilon 2\} \right) + P \left( \{ \nu \in \Omega \mid g(X) (\nu) > \tfrac \epsilon 2\} \right). \end{align*}

Comment: First, thank you for the quick reply! I had been attempting to prove the first line (inclusion of sets):
$$ \{ \nu \in \Omega \mid f(X)(\nu) + g(X)(\nu) > \epsilon \} \subset \{ \nu \in \Omega \mid f(X) (\nu) > \tfrac \epsilon 2\} \ \cup \ \{ \nu \in \Omega \mid g(X) (\nu) > \tfrac \epsilon 2\}. $$
 without success, could you point out the reasoning?

Comment: Basically, we need to prove that if $f + g > \epsilon$, then either $f > \epsilon / 2$ or $g > \epsilon / 2$. Let's prove the contrapositive. If $f \leq \epsilon / 2$ and $g \leq \epsilon / 2$, then certainly $f + g \leq \epsilon$.

Comment: Oh I see! I was being very silly then. Thanks a lot for your answer!